# Can I put a resistor in the ground connection of my DHT22 sensor?

Tags: hardware, temperature-sensor, current

I'm building a project that uses a couple of Adafruit DTH22 temp/humidity sensors. (https://www.adafruit.com/product/385)

I have them wired into my project box through 3.5mm mini plugs (The kind that are commonly used by stereo earbud headphones for MP3 players.)

More than half the time, when I plug/unplug one of my sensors, my Arduino restarts.

My guess is that as I plug in the plug, it sometimes momentarily shorts +5V and ground, causing the +5 source to my Arduino to lose voltage.

These sensors apparently draw single-digit mA of current at peak (like 1.5mA, according to the spec.)

Could I wire a 120Ω or 150Ω resistor in line with the ground connection to the DHT22? This would limit the max current it could carry to around 40mA, which would not be a problem for my power supply (which is fed through the USB port on the Arduino, and thus is limited to 500mA.) Putting a resistor on the ground would limit the current to ground from either the VCC connection to the sensor or the data connection. It would also cause a small loss of voltage to both the data line and the VCC connection.

Would the serial connection between the DHT22 and my Arduino tolerate a 120Ω resistor, even if I connect it via ≈15M of 28-gauge wire?

I could also put the resistor into the VCC wire, but that would only current-limit a VCC-to-ground short, not data-to-ground.

Comment: perhaps you need to determine the cause for the resets before you start formulating a solution ..... how are the mini plugs wired?

Comment: Outer barrel: ground Middle: hot. Tip: Data

Comment: They work just fine unless I plug/unplug them while the arduino is powered up. It seems fairly likely that the act of plugging a mini-plug into the socket might momentarily short one or more of the pins together, and if +5 and ground were to touch, it would exhibit exactly that symptom.

Comment: If you were to change your wiring so that data was in the middle, that would cure your problem without resorting to fudges, yes?

Comment: Likely yes, that would cause it to connect +5 to data, or data to ground as the connector is pushed home. However, I've got 5 different sockets on my project, all of which follow this wiring convention, so it would be a bunch of rework to change it (Changing both the socket wiring and the cables)

Comment: Adding current limiting resistors would be much simpler if that would work.

Comment: A resistor could help, the DHT only draws microamps, iirc.

Comment: Wow... 5 sockets... That's a *huge* amount of work. I suggest you take this opportunity to do it right before you add any more sockets...

Comment: DuncanC, a signal is relative to ground, you can put a resistor in the 5v line. With the plug on the sensor side and according to @Majenko the 5v at the tip, data in the middle, extra resistor of 150Ω from arduino 5v to "tip" (deepest part in the socket). I think that should work. Are they all gold plated or at least sturdy connections?

Comment: They're sturdy connections. I don't think they're gold plated however.

Answer (score 1):

Your case :
   Check wire (shors ?) and pin configuration (out ??)

General :
 No resistor in a ground path.

Decoupling supply :
  one can insert a 100 Ohms resistor between the arduino +5V and the +5V sensor : but ALWAYS use a decoupling capacitor : connect a 100µF betwen +5V sensor and groud. One can add a 100nF ceramic in paraller for digital devices.

Safety in case of bad I/O config :
  Using a 1kOhms restisor between Arduino and Device is good, if next to the Arduino (not at the other end of sensor cable, or use 330 Ohms at eatch end of cable).